# How to handle null when overloading operator + for a class value object?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I want to have to have a value object that represents length. I would prefer to use a `struct` given that it is a value type, but since zero length does not make sense I am forced to use a `class`. Adding two lengths together seems like a reasonable operation, so I want to overload the `+` operator. I am curious though, how should I handle adding `null`?

Adding `null` to an existing string returns a string with the same content as the existing string. Adding `null` to a `int?` that has a value returns `null`.

I can see a case where adding `null`to an existing length simply returns a new length with the same value as the existing length. At the same time, I can see a case where adding `null` would be considered a bug. I have been trying to find some guidance but have not been able to find any. Is there a common guideline for this or is it different for each application?

Comment: Null length makes not much more sense than zero length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using `struct` for your length, and treating the default representation as zero length.

> since zero length does not make sense I am forced to use a `class`

It is up to your code to treat the default representation of length `struct` as a representation of some specific length. In addition to treating it as zero length, you have at least two options:

- You can treat default length as an unknown, in which case any operation with it would produce an unknown, or
- You can treat it as a "trap representation" of length, in which case any operation with it would produce an exception.

It is probably a design mistake to not treat zeros in a uniform way with all other numbers. Specifically, zero length may become handy when you subtract length values, because subtracting two values of equal length would have nothing to produce.

As far as "unknown" length is concerned, using `struct` gives you a convenient standard representation of `Nullable<length>` immediately familiar to users of your `length` structure.

Comment: Given that I want to have a restriction on the length argument in the constructor, `>0`, I disliked using structs. However, `lengthA - lengthB` can indeed result in zero length, in which case we need to be able to handle such. So either I do not overload the standard arithmic operators or I allow zero length objects. The latter seems to be preferred. Completely missed that point.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a null length doesn't exist in reality, everything has length. Getting a null return or a `NullReferenceException` when working with your struct would lead me to think I messed up the constructor or instantiation. In other words,  the null reference would be employed in the scope of the application and not exposed to the client.

```
struct length = new MyStruct(); //no!
struct length = new MyStruct(double feet, double inches) //better...

struct length = 34.5; //ok...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: 
if your allowed to add nulls in your system then you should probably keep the existing value and treat it like a 0 like so:

```
public static NullNumber operator+ (NullNumber b, NullNumber c) {
    return (b ?? 0) + (c ?? 0); 
}
```

Advanced Answer: 
You are probably correct about length not making sense at 0 and you are right about adding nulls seems like a bug 
I can't see where the field is populated but I suspect either:
you don't have a constructor that requires you to pass in a length if it's required.
Or you have a faulty class that sometimes has a length and sometimes meaning it sounds closer to 2 classes